# epoll_create cleanup?

Tags: linux, sockets

I'm using epoll_create to wait on a socket.

What is the life-cycle of the returned resource tied to? Is there something like an epoll_destroy or is it tied to the socket's close or destory call?

Can I re-use the result of epoll_create if close my socket and re-open a new one. Or should I just call epoll_create and forget about the previous result of epoll_create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`epoll_create(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_create.2.html) returns a [*file descriptor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), so you just use [`close(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/close.2.html) on it when done.

Then, the idea of I/O multiplexing, often called [**`Asynchronous I/O`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O), is to wait for multiple events, and handle them one at a time. That means you generally need only one polling file descriptor.

[`epoll(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html) manual page contains basic example of suggested API usage.

Comment: The man page doesn't say to call close or show that in the example. Will do close though, thanks.

Comment: That's because exiting the process cleans up open file descriptors. In a long-running process you want to close those since there's a limit on how many you can have open at a time (`ulimit -n`).

Comment: I need my process to run for hours and days without leaking resources. Generally, speaking, this is not possible without cleaning up explicitly.